# ValueConverter behaves like singleton

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, valueconverter

I have a ValueConverter which needs an external stateful module to work. So I've inherited it from Freezable and declare dependency propery.

```
public class Decorator : Freezable, IValueConverter
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlighterProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Highlighter", typeof (IHighlighter), typeof (Decorator), new PropertyMetadata(null));

  public ITypeNameHighlighter TypeNameHighlighter
  {
    get { return (ITypeNameHighlighter)GetValue(TypeNameHighlighterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TypeNameHighlighterProperty, value); }
  }
  //...
}
```

Then I use DataTemplate and DataTemplateSelector to display a View.
Create an instance of Decorator in resources and use it in binding

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ViewTemplate">
...

<ListView ...>
  <Control.Resources>
    <GUI:Decorator x:Key="Decorator" **Highlighter="{Binding Highlighter}"** />
  </Control.Resources>
...

<GridViewColumn>
  <GridViewColumnHeader  ... />

    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <GUI:RichTextBlock RichText="{Binding Path=Title, Converter={**StaticResource Decorator**}}" />
      </DataTemplate>
  </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
</ListView>
...
</DataTemplate>
```

Problem is when several instances of View are created all of them uses one (first) instance of Decorator to convert an entity to RichText (while in fact several instances of Decorator are created - one by view). 
Highlighter has a state and that is why it is needed that each View must use its own instance of Decorator.

Any comments why there is such behavior?
Any ideas how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**
D J asked me "why you need multiple instances of converter" so I'll describe the task.

There are several instances of the same View in the application. Each View contains its own text filter to filter out elements from the ListView. There is a Highlighter on the ViewModel side which has a filter text and string (ListView element title in our case) as an input and returns information what parts of title matches the filter text. Decorator converts has a title and information returned from the Highlighter as an input and RichText as the output.

I agree that ValueConverter in the form as it offered by WPF is not very suitable for the problem. But I do not see any other elegant way to do it on the View side.

Ed.ward

Answer (score 0):

Put x:Shared=False where you declare the resource of converter. On everycall it will give you new object.

```
<GUI:Decorator x:Shared=False x:Key="Decorator" **Highlighter="{Binding Highlighter}"** />
```

Comment: Shared attribute in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' can be used only in compiled resource dictionaries. Error at object 'Decorator' in markup file ..


Moreover I mentioned in the original post that "...in fact several instances of Decorator are created - one by view". Problem is despite that several instances of Decorator are created only one is used as ValueConverter.

Comment: why you need multiple instances of converter? purpose of converter is to convert from one form to another. but i think you are trying to maintain the state of a process in converter which is wrong.

Comment: I've just updated the original post hope it answers your question